# How to add a badge to the Flutter material app menu button?

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

I want to add an indicator of new content available (like a red dot on the image below) to the Flutter material app menu button.

How it can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use dart's [badges](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/badges) library which is doing exactly this effect on `IconButton` widgets, it comes with useful parameters such as an `badgeColor` and `badgeTextColor`. You can add it into your project using the following steps:

in your `pubspec.yaml` file add:

```
 badges: ^0.0.6 //latest version as of the time of writing the answer
```

then run the `flutter packages get` command,after that you can use it by importing it using the following line:

```
  import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
```

Comment: But can it be used without number on badge?

Comment: yes, there's the property of  `hideZeroCount`,set it to `false` and if the number persists just make its color matches that of the badge and the problem would be solved.